# Total time complexity in a method

Tags: big-o

Folks, lets say I have a method called `sortAndPrint(int[] array)`. Inside the method I have an algorithm that sorts the `array` using Quicksort algorithm and then prints all of the elements of the `array`. My question would the total time complexity of both operations - sorting and printing - be `O(n)` or `O(n + logN)`? Thanks in advance!

```
public void sortAndPrint(int[] array){
    //Use Quicksort alrogithm to sort the array first
    ...........
    ...........

   //Print all of the elements of the array
   ..........
   ..........
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`O(nlogn)+O(n)`~`O(nlogn)` (quicksort on average `O(nlogn)` worst case `O(n^2)` )

`O(nlogn)` dominates `O(n)`..so it is `O(nlogn)`. Whole programs complexity. As simple as this.

For large n the quicksort will take much time than that of `O(n)` printing.

Note: How do you come up with `O(n+logn)`? shouldn't it be `O(n+nlogn)`?

Answer (score -1):

it is O(nlogn). In the notation O(n)+O(n)+O(n) = O(n)